# Add another column to pandas dataframe that adds based on previous values of the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
rng = pd.date_range('2019-02-24', periods=5, freq='H')
rng2 = pd.date_range('2019-02-25', periods=3, freq='H')
test = pd.DataFrame({'id': [111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111],
                    'date': rng.append(rng2)})
test["next_date"] = test.groupby("id")["date"].shift(-1)
test["step_hours"] = (pd.to_datetime(test['next_date'], utc=True) - pd.to_datetime(test['date'], utc=True)).astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

For simplification, let's think we have only one id. For each id, I would like another column that computes session number. If the number of hours - column *step_hours* is less than 5, then those datetimes belong to the same session. If not, it will start another session, previous session + 1.

In our example, we have 2 sessions: session 1: test[:4], session 2: test[4:7]
I tried using rolling, but it does not work on my example because I don't have fixed periods of time.
I tried shift, but it does not seem to do what I want:

```
test['session'] = 1
test['session'] = np.where(test['step_hours']<=5, test['session'].shift(1), test['session'].shift(1)+1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please include what `rng` is referencing?